# How to safely update an existing Kubernetes server without original configurations

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I was handed a Kubernetes cluster with no config files, and was not setup with helm. The author said they just created everything from the cmd line. It is a small/new cluster for a single API server with an nginx ingress controller. I know enough of Kubernetes to get around and was able to add a new web server, but now I need to get in deeper and update existing configs. Specifically, I want to enable prometheus metrics on the nginx controller, but I don't want to break anything.

Is there a standard way to retrieve the existing configurations (deployments, services, etc) from the cluster, make modifications, and apply them? Or is there a way to patch in updates to individual parts of the existing configuration without having to create a new yaml file?

I understand I can get the current config with something like this:

```
kubectl get services -n nginx -o yaml
```

That output has additional fields like creationTimestamp, uid, etc, that I suppose I need to remove. Or can I just save the output exactly as is to a yaml file, make my modifications to enable prometheus, and then apply the config back to the controller?  Will it ignore the kube-created fields? Is there a different approach I should be considering?

Secondly, should I store these configurations in a repository, or is this just how things are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have almost anything you need; there are only some minor considerations:

- `kubectl -n <ns> get <CRD> -o yaml` will give you the output with some read-only identificators, which you cannot redefine even if they will keep theis values, so these aren't suited to keep them as plain files.
- use `kubectl edit instead`
- as about should you keep these in any VCS you want, or should you just make modifications on the fly - it's entirely up to you to decide; any attempt to discuss this will probably start a flame.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was missing.  I'm okay with taking an approach that 50% consider valid.  I'm sure I will come to a conclusion on that myself as I get more insight and experience with Kube.